# ElasticSearch multi level parent-child aggregation

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, aggregation

I have a parent/child structure in 3 levels. Let's say:

> Company -> Employee -> Availability

Since Availability (and also Employee) is frequently updated here, I choose using parent/child structure against nested. And search function works fine (all documents in correct shards).

Now I want to sort those results. Sorting them by meta data from company (1st level) is easy. But I need to sort also by 3rd level (availability).

I want list of companies which are sorted by:

- Distance from location given ASC
- Rating DESC
- Soonest availability ASC

For example:

Company A is 5 miles away, has rating 4 and soonest one of their employees is available in 20 hours
Company B is also 5 miles away, also has rating 4 but soonest one of their employee is available in 5 hours.

Therefore sort result needs to be B, A.

I would like to append special weight to each of this data, so I started writing aggregations which I could later use in my custom_score script.

**[Full gist for creating index, importing data and searching](https://gist.github.com/PeteMinus/13617fe53973fed79f64)**

 
Now, I've managed to write a query which actually returns back result, but availability aggregation bucket is empty.
However, I'm also getting results back too structured, I would like to flatten them.

Currently I get back:

> Company IDS -> Employee IDS -> first availability

I would like to have aggregation like:

> **Company IDS -> first availability**

This way I'm able to do my `custom_score` script to calculate score and sort them properly.

More simplified question:
How can one sort/aggregate by multi level (grand)children and possibly flatten the result.

Comment: Could you add your mapping and a few example docs (with descendants) to the gist? It's hard to see how to invent fake docs that allow adequate testing of your system.

Comment: Hey Sloan - I've added mapping and sample results. I've stripped it  bit for easier understanding. Full stack has lot's more data in it :) Thanks!

Comment: I had the same question [here](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Help-Flattened-aggregations-with-limiting-and-sorting-td4065217.html).  Albeit probably less performant, I just request for all the results which has a default sort of DocCount.  I then did my own recursive flattening, sorting & limiting, which wasn't ideal.

Comment: I've executed your gist, but when searching I get error 500 `Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: NullPointerException;`. Can you execute your gist on your local environment and make sure it is ok? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't create equation for your results. Your data not fuzzy ! You aggregate every query? .  Aggregate is input actions, not an query or output. A question "how you check this result's is True(right) ?"

Comment: Which version of ElasticSearch is used? I obtain a "nullPointerException" (I guess because of my version). I used 1.4.5 version.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need aggregations to do this:

These are the sort criteria:

1. Distance ASC (company.location)
2. Rating DESC (company.rating_value)
3. Soonest Future Availability ASC (company.employee.availability.start)

If you ignore #3, then you can run a relatively simple **company** query like this:

```
GET /companies/company/_search
{
 "query": { "match_all" : {} },
 "sort": {
    "_script": {
        "params": {
            "lat": 51.5186,
            "lon": -0.1347
        },
        "lang": "groovy",
        "type": "number",
        "order": "asc",
        "script": "doc['location'].distanceInMiles(lat,lon)"
    },
    "rating_value": { "order": "desc" }
  }
}
```

**#3** is tricky because you need to reach down and find the availability ( **company > employee > availability** ) for each company closest to the time of the request and use that duration as a *third* sort criterion.

We're going to use a `function_score` query at the grandchild level to take the time difference between the request time and each availability in the hit `_score`.  (Then we'll use the `_score` as the third sort criterion).

To reach the grandchildren we need to use a `has_child` query inside a `has_child` query.

For each company we want the soonest available Employee (and of course their closest Availability).  Elasticsearch 2.0 will give us a `"score_mode": "min"` for cases like this, but for now, since we're limited to `"score_mode": "max"` we'll make the grandchild `_score` be the *reciprocal* of the time-difference.

```
          "function_score": {
            "filter": { 
              "range": { 
                "start": {
                  "gt": "2014-12-22T10:34:18+01:00"
                } 
              }
            },
            "functions": [
              {
                "script_score": {
                  "lang": "groovy",
                  "params": {
                      "requested": "2014-12-22T10:34:18+01:00",
                      "millisPerHour": 3600000
                   },
                  "script": "1 / ((doc['availability.start'].value - new DateTime(requested).getMillis()) / millisPerHour)"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
```

So now the `_score` for each grandchild (**Availability**) will be `1 / number-of-hours-until-available` (so that we can use the *maximum reciprocal* time until available per Employee, and the *maximum reciprocal(ly?)* available Employee per Company).

Putting it all together, we continue to query **company** but use **company > employee > availabilty** to generate the `_score` to use as the **#3** sort criterion:

```
GET /companies/company/_search
{
 "query": { 
    "has_child" : {
        "type" : "employee",
        "score_mode" : "max",
        "query": {
          "has_child" : {
            "type" : "availability",
            "score_mode" : "max",
            "query": {
              "function_score": {
                "filter": { 
                  "range": { 
                    "start": {
                      "gt": "2014-12-22T10:34:18+01:00"
                    } 
                  }
                },
                "functions": [
                  {
                    "script_score": {
                      "lang": "groovy",
                      "params": {
                          "requested": "2014-12-22T10:34:18+01:00",
                          "millisPerHour": 3600000
                       },
                      "script": "1/((doc['availability.start'].value - new DateTime(requested).getMillis()) / millisPerHour)"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
 },
 "sort": {
  "_script": {
    "params": {
        "lat": 51.5186,
        "lon": -0.1347
    },
    "lang": "groovy",
    "type": "number",
    "order": "asc",
    "script": "doc['location'].distanceInMiles(lat,lon)"
  },
  "rating_value": { "order": "desc" },
  "_score": { "order": "asc" }
 }
}
```

Comment: You may get slightly better performance using a [linear decay function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay) rather than a script to generate `_score` from *time-until-available*.

Comment: Elasticsearch disabled dynamic scripting by default. Better is to use indexed scripts. See here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting

Comment: Pete Minus:  Were you able to get this working?  I know this is an older question, however there are a lot of people interested in your solution.

Comment: Peter Dixon-Moses: Eventually I gave up and wrote two queries - first to search by Company/Employee and then search for top 100 Companies through Availability and then merge. Why? It was taking too much time/effort to build it only in ES. Time spent for search is acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

You should check out R-Tree data structure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree.